Cygwin will no longer start shell
Have used Cygwin for years. One thing is just to have a proper command line on my Windows machine.  Suddenly, it no longer will start the terminal.  It was just not doing anything, so I changed the shortcut to hold on error.  My shortcut now runs
C:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe --hold error -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico -

And now it says that "This account is currently not available" and /sbin/nologin: Exit 1

It happened just before I went on holiday, so my recollection isn't 100% of the order but I think it happened after a Windows update.  I did also have to change my password for my domain account around that time.
I have tried emptying the cache folder for the cygwin installer and re-installing mintty and anything with "bash" in the title.  No help.  Running as administrator gives the same result.
I'm running Windows 11 Pro 23H2.
What can be wrong?  Where should I look next?

Don't know what caused it, but the following fixed it

Create an archive of everything in my cygwin home folder (I used 7zip)
Empty my cygwin home fodler
Run the cygwin installer and re-install everything in base and shells packages that I had installed
Restore my home folder from the archive
Manually recreate the symlinks I had from my home folder

Note sure if anything other than the re-install was needed, but I'd tried it first.
